# Interviewer didn't call back

Tags: interviewing

Recently I had an interview with reputed company for Maintenance technician position.
I called the interviewer(HR of the company) on given time, and greeted well. She's like hold on, let me get your resume. I have waited for 5 minutes, and after 5 minutes She's like I am not getting your resume. I did send her again on mail. And shes like yeah I received but can I call you after 5-10 miutes as I have to go in team meeting. I agreed and waited and never received call for whole day. I mailed her and wrote, i am free anytime for a week to have interview again. And she never replied and i called her too but she disconnected my call. What can be the reason. I know we can't do anything, but will it be good to call or mail her again for the same?

Comment: "I know we can't do anything" Correct.

Comment: Keep applying for new jobs. Forget about this one.

Answer (score 4):

> I know we can't do anything, but will it be good to call or mail her again for the same?

What would be best for your interests is to move on and continue applying.

The reasons why this interviewer acted that way and aren't calling is something we can only guess, and still won't help you.

Continue applying to jobs you like and you'll land an offer eventually. Good luck.

Comment: Either they will get back to you or they won't. In either case, unless there is something exceptional about this particular employer and position, the best place to invest your efforts now is in +further applications.

Answer (score 3):

> What can be the reason. I know we can't do anything, but will it be
> good to call or mail her again for the same?

It won't hurt to send an email.

But most likley they aren't interested. Don't stop your job search.